# How to return an XML string after authentication in SimpleSamlPhp

Tags: simplesamlphp

I am new to SimpleSamlPhp, I already setup a working environment, it is able to redirect to an URL @ metadata\saml20-sp-remote.php

Example:

```
$metadata['http://www.example.com'] = array(
    'AssertionConsumerService' => 'http://www.example.com/acceptsaml.php',
    'SingleLogoutService' => 'http://www.example.com/saml2-logout.php',
);
```

How to pass extra custom fields (I added new custom fields, example: EmployeeID, in auth_user table) as XML/Json after authentication redirect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [authProc filters](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc) to add new attributes to the XML asserted by your IdP. The `auth` source you use may also have additional options for adding/naming attributes.

```
$metadata['myEntityId'] = array(
        'host' => 'my-hostname',
        'privatekey' => 'key.pem',
        'certificate' => 'pub.crt',
        'auth' => 'auth-source',
        'signature.algorithm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256',
        'attributes.NameFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri',
        'authproc' => array(
            50 => array(
               'class' => 'core:AttributeAdd',
               'myAttribute' => array('some-value'),
            ),
         ),
);
```